# How to solve TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'paid' in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

I am implementing custom user model extending AbstractBaseUser. 
Here is my account/models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password
        )

        user.paid = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    list_filter = ()  # Con
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ("paid",)
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.is_admin
```

But I am getting the error while creating super user with the command `python manage.py runserver`

This is what I got from the terminal :

```
Email: i@j.com
Paid: True
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
    File "manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
      output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/home/rhidwan/Desktop/shotave/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 156, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'paid'
```

Previously this worked fine about 4 days ago when I last checked. But it stopped working from today. Not sure what is the problem. I didn't do any update of the packages. And can't remember If I deleted any of the code.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
There is how I solved the problem. 
I removed all of my migrations and then changed paid field to is_paid. And then apply migrations again and it works like charm.

Thanks everyone who helped a lot to get the problem solved.

Comment: Just add `*args` and/or `**kwargs` into your functions. `def create_superuser(self, email, password, *args, **kwargs):` so that when people call these function, they can pass what ever param they want, but your function only handle what ever param you care and ignore the rest.

Comment: Why is Paid a required field? Paid has default value as False. Plus you can addd *args and **kwargs to your `create_superuser` method.

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal Tried commenting this, But same error

Answer (score 1):

Your `create_superuser` does not accept any keyword argument `paid`. It just accepts `email` and `password`. But you have added it to [REQUIRED_FIELDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS), hence it will be passed to `create_superuser` while creating a superuser.

You have to update your [create_superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_superuser) and [create_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_user) methods to accept that field.

One simple solution is to change:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    ...
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password
    )
```

To:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    ...
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        **extra_fields,
    )
```

And change:

```
def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    ...
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
    )
```

To:

```
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    ...
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        **extra_fields,
    )
```

After that, in the future, you will be able to add other fields as well to `REQUIRED_FIELDS` without changing code.

Answer (score 1):

When using [REQUIRED_FIELDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS) in your User model, the `python manage.py createsuperuser` command will prompt you to enter the required fields and it then sends the field to [create_superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser) module of your manager.

Since you're already initializing the paid field in your `create_superuser()` method, you can do one of the things from below:

1. If you want to set the paid parameter on command prompt, remove `paid=True` from your `create_superuser()` function and change it as below:

```
    def create_superuser(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            **kwargs
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

2. Or if you want to be specific with parameters, you can do pass the paid parameter in function arguments:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password, paid):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password
        )

        user.paid = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

3. If `paid=True` is always a True condition for `SUPERUSER`, you can remove it from `REQUIRED_FIELDS` but this will also be removed for a normal user then but the default will be set to False as per your models.